# How to order the output of an array in php by the date of the values?

Tags: php

I have an array as below.  I simply want to order the echoing of it by date, so we have the most recent date at the top.  I'm not sure though if a.  php can order arrays, and b.  whether it can read the date in the format it is in.  I can change the format it is capture din if that would make it easier?

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
    [month_year] => September2012
    [vimeo_link] => http://vimeo.com/472
    )
    [1] => Array (
    [month_year] => July2012
    [vimeo_link] => https://vimeo.com/460
    )
    [2] => Array (
    [month_year] => August2012
    [vimeo_link] => https://vimeo.com/490
    )

)
```

```php
foreach($rows as $row){?>

    <li><a target="_blank" href="<?php echo $row['vimeo_link'];?>"><?php echo $row['month_year'];?></a></li>            
<?php
    }?>
```

Comment: You'd need to use usort() with a custom callback function that converted the date strings to date/timestamps for comparison

Comment: Plese check : http://www.krio.me/sort-an-array-in-php-by-date/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
$rows = Array(
        "0" => Array("month_year" => "September2012","vimeo_link" => "http://vimeo.com/472"),
        "1" => Array("month_year" => "July2012","vimeo_link" => "https://vimeo.com/460"),
        "2" => Array("month_year" => "August2012","vimeo_link" => "https://vimeo.com/490"));

usort($rows, function ($a, $b) {
    $a = DateTime::createFromFormat("FY", $a['month_year']);
    $b = DateTime::createFromFormat("FY", $b['month_year']);
    return ($a == $b) ? 0 : (($a < $b) ? - 1 : 1);
});


foreach ( $rows as $row ) {
    printf("<li><a target=\"_blank\" href=\"%s\">%s</a></li>", $row['vimeo_link'], $row['month_year']);
}
```

Output

July2012

August2012

September2012

Comment: thanks very much, what do I do to make that the other way, so the most recent month is at the top?

Comment: also, why have do you use printf and not echo?  I see this in wordpress and am not sure what it does.

Comment: just changed the `<` to `>` and that changed the order.

Comment: Yes that is all you need to do

Comment: `printf()` is a way to insert variables into a string... see the two `%s` in the string and the two variables that follow.

Comment: ahh, so the %s just follow in order of the declaring of the values?  i.e. the first %s is the first declared variable?  What's the advantage of using this method over echo?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to convert those month/date string into valid dates or timestamps, then you will want to look at `usort()`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php